# ConcurrentDictionary on large numbers

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I wonder to know why `ConcurrentDictionary` `getOrAdd` method slows down heavily as entry number grows up.

I call it inside 3 nested loops and, printing to file the time of each innest loop, I can see that the execution time of each innest loop grows linearly and I don't know why, since each innest loop is of the same size. I was guessing that it is some matter of `ConcurrentDictionary`, but that's the reason for I'm asking here.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What are you adding to it? Does the key class have a proper GetHashCode method?

Comment: the key class is a Vector3, so yes

Comment: Are you sure the filewriting isn't what's causing the linear growth in time?

Comment: I didn't post my code because I think it would be misleading. By the way, fortunately, Michał Komorowski was able to get the point. So, if you don't mind, I would not apply any change to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of collisions. *ConcurrentDictionary* maintains a list of buckets and the result returned by *GetHashCode* method determines in which bucket an entry will be placed. Ideally each entry should be in the seperate bucket. However, in practise it is not possible. If *GetHashCode* returns the same value for 2 different keys, the collision appears and more and more entries is placed in the same bucket.

Under the hood, each bucket is implemented as the linked list. Every time, when the collision is detected a dictionary has to scan some linked list in order to check if a given entry is already there. The more elements is in this dictionary, the longer linked lists will be and the more time will be required to iterate through them.

By the way, standard *Dictionary* is implemented in the different way but will behave in the similar manner. The nice description of internals of both data structures can be found [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/02/22/inside-the-concurrent-collections-concurrentdictionary/)